# Being washed two weeks ago

Tags: present-participles, participle-clauses, participle-phrases

Is "being" okay in the following? What difference does it make if it is removed?

> (Being) washed two weeks ago, the car still looks spotlessly clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not wrong to use "being", but as WendyG says, most native speakers would probably choose "having been".  It makes more sense to describe washing as a relative action, especially (as stangdon points out) if it was washed in the past.

> **Having been given** a fresh coat of paint, the house looks practically new.

If instead you were to describe it as a current quality of of the car, "being" would be fine:

> **Being** recently washed and waxed, the car practically sparkles in the sunlight.

Some sort of participle phrase is required, but it doesn't have to be in the present participle "-ing" form.  The past participle phrase "washed two weeks ago" is fine.

> Recently **washed and waxed**, the car looks brand new.

The main problem with your example sentence is the logic doesn't quite work with this grammar.  Because you use "still", it sounds like you want to draw attention to an extraordinary situation.  In that case you would say something like:

> **Although** washed two weeks ago, the car still looks spotlessly clean.
>
> **Despite** having been washed two weeks ago, the car still looks spotlessly clean.

Answer (score 2):

In that particular sentence, where the main clause has "the car *still looks* clean", **Being washed** is ungrammatical.

You can more readily hear that is ungrammatical when you reverse the order of the clauses:

> The car still looks clean, being washed two weeks ago. <sup>No</sup>
>
> The car, being washed two weeks ago, still looks clean.  <sup>No</sup>

Consider:

> Being given a sedative two hours ago, the patient is still asleep. <sup>No</sup>

This is OK:

> Washed two weeks ago, the car still looks clean. <sup>grammatical</sup>
>
> Given a sedative two hours ago, the patient is still asleep. <sup>grammatical</sup>
>
> The car, washed two weeks ago, still looks clean.  <sup>grammatical</sup>
>
> The patient, given a sedative two hours ago, is still asleep. <sup>grammatical</sup>

Answer (score 0):

(Being) washed two weeks ago, the car still looks spotlessly clean.

Should be, to be expressed smoothly and idiomatically:

-**As it was washed two weeks ago**
-**Since it was washed two week ago**

Since and as show a condition or state.

There need to use a participle phrase here and it is pretty awkward in that sentence.